# Jest test, debug using dev tools

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am trying to use chrome dev tools to debug my tests. I have a simple test setup using `jest`

```
describe('App component renders the todo correctly', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const rendered = renderer.create(
      <App />
    );
    expect(rendered.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

using:     `"test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch --silent",`

I can go into `chrome://inspect/#devices` and click `Open dedicated DevTools for Node`

However, in the resulting `dev tools` window, I can't see anything to debug. I am expecting a process where I can set breakpoints and inspect data.

How can I debug my tests in `dev tools`?

Comment: what command are you using to run the tests?

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/troubleshooting.html

Essentially: add a `debug;` statement in a test of yours. Then run:

`node debug --debug-brk node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js -i`

Answer (score 0):

```
node debug --debug-brk node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js -i
```

(node:340) [DEP0068] DeprecationWarning: `node debug` is deprecated. Please use `node inspect` instead.
< C:\Program Files\no
< dejs\node.exe: [DEP0062]: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` and `node --inspect-brk` instead.

use this

```
node --inspect-brk node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runInBand
```